# Custom Nav Menu items default to 'menu-item-type' => 'custom'. How to make a "page" menu item?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm using the code below to create custom menu items on the fly. Its working great, except all menus are created as "Custom". In the code below, setting the menu-item-type to 'page' appears to have no effect.

```
        foreach($thePages as $page){
            wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
                'menu-item-title' => $page->post_title,
                'menu-item-type' => 'page', 
                'menu-item-status' => 'publish')
            );          
        }
```

wp-includes/nav-menu.php shows that the value is hard coded to "Custom". However, if I manually add a page to the menu, using the WP Menus manager, it lists it as "Page", not "Custom". What can I do to set the menu type to "Page"?

Comment: I've used the filter 'nav_menu_css_class' to modify the css classes. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Wild Phoenix: I'm creating a custom menu on the fly, then iterating over the top level pages and assigning each of them to the custom menu. This is all done via a plugin during its activation hook. Its not related to css at all at this point. I'm just trying to figure out how to get each menu registered as a "Page" and not as "Custom" in my code above.

Comment: try setting `menu-item-object-id` in your array to the page id

Comment: @baininternet: Will do. Thanks to the help and suggestion.

Comment: @bainternet: This didn't work. Still shows as "Custom". 'menu-item-object-id' =>  $page->ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a filter:

```
function wpse15368_update_menu_item_type( $args )
{
    return $args['menu-item-type'] = 'page';
}
add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', 'wpse15368_update_menu_item_type' );
```

Comment: As @lulalala below points out, `post_type` is indeed the key word to use. @lulalala has the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

Strange it maybe, `post_type' is the keyword to use:

```
'menu-item-object' => 'page',
'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
'menu-item-object-id' => $post_id
```

This will make a menu item just like you manually created one.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, thanks for sharing.